# Temperature needed to make crunchy toffee

Tags: toffee

I'm trying to make chocolate nut toffee and all the recipes I've found tells you to boil the toffee until it's dark brown. What temperature does it have to reach to achieve that?  The toffee should be crunchy and not sticky.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> Toffee is a confection made by caramelizing sugar or molasses
>   (creating inverted sugar) along with butter, and occasionally flour.
>   The mixture is heated until its temperature reaches the hard crack
>   stage of **149 to 154 °C (300 to 310 °F).** While being prepared, toffee
>   is sometimes mixed with nuts or raisins.

As stated here - https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=toffee+temperature

Hope that helps...

Comment: Very useful information.  I haven't been heating it high enough.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @doug Indeed, it is good ettiquette to upvote all seriously intended answers to one's question. But a new user needs some reputation before he can cast upvotes. I don't think Sous chef can do it yet.

Comment: My bad hadn't realised that I'll delete that comment. Accept is possible though?